# Streaming Database(mariadb) Changes into another database table using apache-kafka and debezium connector

Tags: apache-kafka, mariadb, debezium

What I am aiming to do is to Stream data changes into new database table using ***apache-kafka*** along with **debezium-connectors**. But I don't have the slightest idea to how to achieve it. Although I know how to start kafka-zookeeper ,creating topics , and subscribe to that topic . And I am unfamiliar with all the next steps .How to achieve ***data streaming*** and capture that data into new database table using **Change Data Capture(CDC)**?

Answer (score 2):

Debezium only sources data into Kafka. Won't read from Kafka or write to a new database.

You can refer an old blog post of theirs using the JDBC Sink Kafka Connector to write to a new server

https://debezium.io/blog/2017/09/25/streaming-to-another-database/