# Anyone share one sample project link for kafka and mariadb intergration?

Tags: apache-kafka, mariadb, streaming, cdc

I am new to this technology,
my configuration

```
``NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian`
```

`
kafka version

```
3.3.1 (Commit:e23c59d00e687ff5)
```

mariadb version

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.7-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

I need one sample project of integration git link or youtube link anything....

thanks advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may found the answer here -->[Try Check This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72498164/streaming-databasemariadb-changes-into-another-database-table-using-apache-kaf)

Comment: it helped a little but this is not what i am looking for . Thanking you.!

Comment: i need more information